# Need to capture particular output

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

This is the exact output I got from a program:

```
#Meaningless output
[TABL]
BSSID
4c:e6:78:e3:4e:58
a0:8b:16:e3:3a:42

ADMAC=a1:3c:24:e5:2e:22
ADMAC=.......
#Meaningless output
```

I just want to capture the BSSID column along with its mac addresses ONLY and not the ADMAC values or any other values.How can I do that using bash(or grep or sed or awk,anything)?Thanks.

Comment: I see only one column here.

Comment: Only one column was produced in output.I just need to capture the BSSID table and nothing else

Comment: And what is `the BSSID table` in your input file? That's rhetorical - edit your question to include the expected output given that input plus whatever you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/BSSID/{p=1} p&&!NF{exit} p' file

BSSID
4c:e6:78:e3:4e:58
a0:8b:16:e3:3a:42
```

prints after the pattern match until an empty line.

Or, simpler but gets you the empty line at the end.

```
$ awk '/BSSID/,/^$/' file

BSSID
4c:e6:78:e3:4e:58
a0:8b:16:e3:3a:42
<- empty line here ...
```

to filter the last empty line, you can add a condition

```
$ awk '/BSSID/,/^$/{if(NF) print}'
```

note that the first alternative is the most flexible and the preferred one.

Comment: ++; I see you're experiencing a late-afternoon comeback.

Comment: Yeah, I got some caffeine boost.

Comment: Darn just when I was about to upvote you throw in a range expression. If only I could upvote half an answer... OK, upvoted anyway for the answer using a flag,

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It worked on Mac using your example.

```
cat output.txt | awk '/BSSID/,/ADMAC/'| grep -v ADMAC
```

Comment: `awk` can take a file input, not need to `cat`.

Comment: I know but it is easier to experiment this way.

Comment: This is less elegant but does the job in quick and dirty way.

Answer (score 0):

Tell grep to show the two lines after the match and stop after 1 match.

```
grep -m1 -A2 "^BSSID$" output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` to the rescue!

Since the requirement is to include only the MAC addresses, which must include a colon, period, or dash, the following would be reasonable, given the example input:

```
 sed -n '/^BSSID/,/^ *$/ {/[:.-]/p;}'
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have awk try:

```
    awk '{/BSSID/,/ADMAC/ print}' output.txt
```

Comment: Ill do that.Thanks tho!!

Comment: I think syntax is off. it should be `'/BSSID/,/ADMAC/'` but will print the end pattern line as well.

Comment: That's not really even close to idiomatic awk syntax.